# Emberjs: Resetting controller based on dynamic segment

Tags: ember.js

I have this route structure in my app:

```
Profile.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('profile', { path: '/:user' }, function(){
    this.route('followers');
  });
});
```

My `/:user/followers` page is supposed to show the list of followers of `:user`. The controller for `profile.followers` is setup for infinite scroll - so it has properties like `curPage, resultsPerPage`.

```
Profile.ProfileFollowersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(InfiniteScroll.ControllerMixin,{
  curPage: 1,
  resultsPerPage: 20,
  //other code for infinite scroll which increments curPage as user scrolls down
})
```

Now, since controllers are singleton in emberjs, when I move from `/tom/followers` to `/jin/followers`, the properties for infinite scroll that were set for `/tom/followers` get preserved and applied for `/jin/followers` as well.

For eg. say I am on `/tom/followers` and scroll down 4 pages, `curPage` property of `'profile.followers'` controller gets set as 4. Now when I move to `/jin/followers`, though the model hook of the route would return list of followers for jin, but would pick `curPage` as 4 since ember's controllers are singleton and I had scrolled down to 4th page on `/tom/followers`. 
How is this supposed to be handled?

Here is my `profile.followers` route as well:

```
Profile.ProfileFollowersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    console.log("fetching followers model");
    return Ember.$.getJSON('/'+this.modelFor('profile').user+'/followers?new=1');
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `route`'s `setupController` hook for this. This hook is fired every time the route is entered.

```
App.ProfileFollowersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    // Call _super for default behavior
    this._super(controller, model);
    // Reset the desired controller properties
    controller.setProperties({
      curPage: null,
      someOtherProp: null
    });
  }
});
```

I've made a jsbin demonstrating it:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fiyetefeno/6/

You can read the API documentation here:
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController

Comment: Thanks for your effort! But is it the right ember-way of handling this? I don't understand why controller is a singleton if I have to reset various properties everytime.

Comment: Very much the Ember way. Controller state is kept in memory until you flush it by reloading or reset it yourself. This guy explains it beter: http://balinterdi.com/2014/06/26/ember-gotcha-controllers-are-singletons.html